# unique javascript array based on one property

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, unique

I have a multidimensional array in javascript. I want to make it so it shows the first record for each unique "name". So for example this:

```
[{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Aellen , Nick","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"96.88%"},
{"name":"Armstrong , Peter","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"95.15%"},
{"name":"Ashmore , Abigail","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"99.80%"},
{"name":"Avent , Christopher","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"90.11%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"},
```

Would turn into this:

```
[{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Aellen , Nick","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"96.88%"},
{"name":"Armstrong , Peter","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"95.15%"},
{"name":"Ashmore , Abigail","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"99.80%"},
{"name":"Avent , Christopher","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"90.11%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"},
```

Originally It was not multivarite and i could use a basic function, but that method wont work for this one. Any ideas? Pretty desperate! Thanks.

Comment: It's actually an array of objects as opposed to a multi-dimensional array...

Comment: Sorry .. My bad, been going all day :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would create a new array with the first unique records only

```
var obj     = {},
    new_arr = [];

arr.forEach(function(itm) {
    if ( ! (itm.name in obj) ) obj[itm.name] = itm;
});

for (var key in obj) {
    new_arr.push(obj[key]);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWDTb/3/)

Comment: Why don't you just do `new_arr.push(obj)`? Instead of `for in` loop.

Comment: @RahilWazir - because I'm not pushing that object, but the objects contained in that object etc. Just using the names as keys to make sure they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var foos = [{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Aellen , Nick","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"96.88%"},
{"name":"Armstrong , Peter","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"95.15%"},
{"name":"Ashmore , Abigail","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"99.80%"},
{"name":"Avent , Christopher","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"90.11%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"}];

var new_foos = [];

var previous_foo = null;

for (var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    if (previous_foo != foos[i].name)
    {
        new_foos.push(foos[i]);
    }

    previous_foo = foos[i].name;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this requires that foo is sorted. This works if foo is unsorted:

```
var foos = [{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},

{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"},
{"name":"Ashmore , Abigail","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"99.80%"},
{"name":"Baker , Ian Howard","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"67.20%"},
{"name":"Aellen , Nick","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"96.88%"},
{"name":"Armstrong , Peter","col1":"Director","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"95.15%"},{"name":"Adelman , Erica","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"73.77%"},
{"name":"Avent , Christopher","col1":"Vice President","col2":"test","col3":"test","col4":"90.11%"}];

var new_foos = [];

for (var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    var new_foo = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < new_foos.length; j++) {
        if (foos[i].name == new_foos[j].name) {
            new_foo = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (new_foo)
    {
        new_foos.push(foos[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the solution is in Python? :D

Comment: Apparently it has been a loooong day D:

Comment: @War10ck True, I suppose, but it's still usable pseudocode I'd say. I would hope for people to understand the code they're copying and not just copy-paste, so it shouldn't be a big effort to rewrite in JS if you have some level of understanding.

Comment: @Katana314 While this may be true, I don't think it's entirely clear if you're not familiar with `python`. I've written both so I understand what you mean. For someone who hasn't though, I think it could be a little difficult to follow. It's for the reason you said though, that I did not downvote the post and merely commented on it.

Comment: I've never used python but this seems pretty straight forward

Comment: I would note that this algorithm only works if the array is sorted by name.

Comment: That's Python? Looks just like JavaScript to me

Comment: I changed it to JS after a bit of Googling

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I will give it a try and report back!

Comment: I added a version for an unsorted foo as I feel guilty for wasting time with the Python version.